# Program giving one type of output in arduino ide stm32f1xx board version 2019.10.9 giving different output in board verison 2019.12.31

Tags: arduino-ide

```
 void setup() {

      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial1.begin(9600);
      Serial1.println("HM 10 here");
      Serial.println("STM32 here");

    }

 void loop() {

      char inputdata;
      while (Serial1.available()){
      Serial.println("In loop");
      inputdata = (char)Serial1.read();
      Serial.println(inputdata);

    }
```

With this code , I was able to send signals to hm10 and was able to see the sent signals in serial monitor of arduino ide in the 2019.10.9 version but not in 2019.12.31.
I am dumping the code on stm32 using ftdi driver.
I am sending the string "hai" from BLE terminal app.
I updated my arduino library board manager and stm32f1xx board version upgraded to version 2019.12.31.

In stm32f1xx board version 2019.10.9 , when i send values from the app to hm10 , i get this output on serial monitor

```
STM32 here
In loop


In loop
h
In loop
a
In loop
i
In loop


In loop
```

But in the case of stm32f1xx board version 2019.12.31 , i get this output on serial monitor

```
HM 10 here
STM32 here
```

If I have to use any libraries do guide me..

Comment: It is not clear, what the problem is. Am I understanding correct, that you have problems with 2 different board definitions? What do you mean by, that you were able to send signals or where not? What is actually happening, when you send data from the HM10? (Sending data from the PC to the Arduino won't do anything, as you don't have code for that).

Comment: what is "stm32f1xx board version 2019.x.x"? git master branch commits in rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32?

Comment: @chrisl , yes i think the different board versions are giving different output

Comment: @Juraj , I used http://dan.drown.org/stm32duino/package_STM32duino_index.json

Comment: @Juraj , no , I followed from this website - https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/getting-started-with-stm32-development-board-stm32f103c8-using-arduino-ide , i found the package in that link

Comment: I confirmed it on stm32duino forum. This are builds of Roger Clark's STM32 core. This are not releases, but hourly builds published after every commit to the repository. I recommend https://www.stm32duino.com forum